# Jquery off hover?

Tags: jquery

I have this code here:

```
$('.fa').hover(function(){
    $('#hiddenStuff').show();    
});
```

when the user hovers over this element, another element appears, how do I make this element disappear when you hover off the .fa element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) accepts 2 callbacks. The second one is called when the mouse leaves the element:

```
$('.fa').hover(function(){
      $('#hiddenStuff').show();
}, function(){
      $('#hiddenStuff').hide();
});
```

---

Side note: depending on your HTML you can avoid using javascript here:

```css
div {
    padding: 20px;
}
.fa {
    background: lightblue;
}
#hiddenStuff {
    display: none;
    background: yellow;
}
.fa:hover ~ #hiddenStuff {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class=fa>FA (move the mouse over here)</div>
<div id=hiddenStuff>hiddenStuff</div>
```

Comment: To editors: please don't "correct HTML" when it's just your personal preferences

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggle()` method like following.

```js
$('.fa').hover(function(){
    $('#hiddenStuff').toggle();
});
```

```css
#hiddenStuff{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fa">Hover</span>
<br/>
<span id="hiddenStuff">Show/Hide</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
$('.fa').mouseenter(function(){
//what you want on mouse enter
}

$('.fa').mouseleave(function(){
//what you want on mouse exit
}
```

allows for specificity, as well as using the .hover callback if you'd prefer only using .hover().